# Artifactory - Composer : Add remote dependency

Tags: composer-php, artifactory

I am setting up a Composer repository in Artifactory. I managed to upload our internal package using the REST API.
Now I would like to cache external packages (required by our own packages) into Artifactory, in order to avoid using packagist.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you created Remote Repository to the remote site?

Comment: Yes, I created a Remote Repository